# How to get/set the colour of the worksheet tab using xlwings in Python?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

The following example comes from the [documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_tab_colors.html) of `xlsxwriter`:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('tab_colors.xlsx')

# Set up some worksheets.
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet3 = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet4 = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Set tab colors
worksheet1.set_tab_color('red')
worksheet2.set_tab_color('green')
worksheet3.set_tab_color('#FF9900')  # Orange

# worksheet4 will have the default color.

workbook.close()
```

Is it possible to do the same in xlwings? I do not see anything in the code of the class Sheet related to colours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, it is possible to get and set the colours of a tab using the pywin32 api. Please note that it makes your code platform specific and it will not work on Mac for example.

```
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings.utils import rgb_to_int, int_to_rgb

# Define RGB codes
green = (226, 239, 218)
grey = (242, 242, 242)
red = (252, 228, 214)

# Connect to the Excel file
wb = xw.Book(EXCEL_FILENAME)

for sht in wb.sheets:
    # Retrieve the tab colour
    print("Sheet name {}, Tab color int: {}, Tab color RGB: {}".format(sht.name, sht.api.Tab.Color, int_to_rgb(sht.api.Tab.Color)))

# Set the tab colour to these existing tabs
wb.sheets["Test Green"].api.Tab.Color = rgb_to_int(green)
wb.sheets["Test Grey"].api.Tab.Color = rgb_to_int(grey)
wb.sheets["Test Red"].api.Tab.Color = rgb_to_int(red)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do with the xlwings api and set the color using the Excel colour number if you know it;
E.g.
255 Red
65280 Green
16711680 Blue
or the RBG colour code
or use the colour index

```
import xlwings as xw
# Set sheet tab to Blue

    wb = xw.Book('tab_colors.xlsx')
    # Either
    wb.sheets['sheet1'].api.Tab.Color = 16711680 
    wb.sheets['sheet2'].api.Tab.Color = '&HFF0000'
    wb.sheets['sheet3'].api.Tab.ColorIndex = 5
```