# Add new sheet with graph

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlwings

newby question.
I would like to add a new sheet to an existing wb that I've created with xlwings.
It seems that when I try to add e write the 2nd sheet the 1st one going to be overwritten.

Here the code :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns # library for visualization
sns.set() # this command sets the seaborn chart style as the default
import xlwings as xw
from datetime import datetime  
df=pd.read_excel('aspire_1909.xls')
df2=df.drop([0,2])
new_header = df2.iloc[1]
df2 = df2[2:]
df2.columns = new_header
df2=df2.set_index('User')
wb = xw.Book()
sht = wb.sheets[0]
sht.name = "Aspire Manager Graph"
sht.range('R1').value = df3
started=len(df3.loc[df3['Manager Review'] == 'Started'])
complete = len(df3.loc[df3['Manager Review'] == 'Complete'])
complete_reopened = len(df3.loc[df3['Manager Review'] == 'Complete (Reopened)'])
not_started = len(df3.loc[df3['Manager Review'] == 'Not Started'])
past_due = len(df3.loc[df3['Manager Review'] == 'Past Due'])
def insert_heading(rng,text):
    rng.value = text
    rng.font.bold = True
    rng.font.size = 24
    rng.font.color = (0,0,139)
insert_heading(sht.range("A2"),f"ASPIRE YEAR END REVIEW - MANAGER STATUS del {datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}")
data = {'Not Started':not_started, 'Started':started, 'Completed':complete,'Reopened' : complete_reopened,'Past Due ' : past_due  }

status = list(data.keys())
values = list(data.values())
x_labels = list(a + ' ' + str(b) for (a, b) in zip(status, values))
 
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))

# creating the bar plot

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
bars = ax.bar(status, values, color =['red','blue','green','yellow','violet'],
    width = 0.4)
ax.bar_label(bars, fmt="%d", fontsize=26, rotation=0, padding=3)
plt.bar(status, values, color =['red','blue','green','yellow','violet'],
        width = 0.4)
plt.xticks(status, x_labels)
plt.xticks(rotation = 45, fontsize = 13)
plt.xlabel("Year End Review Completion Status")
plt.ylabel("No Users",rotation=45,fontsize = 13)
plt.title("Aspire Mgr Year End Review")


plt.show()

sht.pictures.add(fig,
                 name = "Aspire Mgr Status Graph",
                 update = True,
                 left =sht.range("A4").left,
                 top = sht.range("A4").top,
                 height= 500,
                 width= 700)

sht1 = wb.sheets[0]
wb.sheets.add('Aspire Employees Graph')
sht1.range('R1').value = df2

started=len(df2.loc[df2['Aspire year-end reflection (FY22)'] == 'Started'])
complete = len(df2.loc[df2['Aspire year-end reflection (FY22)'] == 'Complete'])
complete_reopened = len(df2.loc[df2['Aspire year-end reflection (FY22)'] == 'Complete (Reopened)'])
not_started = len(df2.loc[df2['Aspire year-end reflection (FY22)'] == 'Not Started'])
past_due = len(df2.loc[df2['Aspire year-end reflection (FY22)'] == 'Past Due'])

def insert_heading(rng,text):
    rng.value = text
    rng.font.bold = True
    rng.font.size = 24
    rng.font.color = (0,0,139)
insert_heading(sht1.range("A2"),f"ASPIRE YEAR END REVIEW EMPLOYEE STATUS del {datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}")

data = {'Not Started':not_started, 'Started':started, 'Completed':complete,'Reopened' : complete_reopened,'Past Due ' : past_due  }

status = list(data.keys())
values = list(data.values())
x_labels = list(a + ' ' + str(b) for (a, b) in zip(status, values))
 
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))

# creating the bar plot

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
bars = ax.bar(status, values, color =['red','blue','green','yellow','violet'],
    width = 0.4)
ax.bar_label(bars, fmt="%d", fontsize=26, rotation=0, padding=3)
plt.bar(status, values, color =['red','blue','green','yellow','violet'],
        width = 0.4)
plt.xticks(status, x_labels)
plt.xticks(rotation = 45, fontsize = 13)
plt.xlabel("Year End Review Completion Status")
plt.ylabel("Nb. Users",rotation=45,fontsize = 13)
plt.title("Aspire Employee Year End Review")


plt.show()
sht1.pictures.add(fig,
                 name = "Aspire Employee Status Graph",
                 update = True,
                 left =sht.range("A4").left,
                 top = sht.range("A4").top,
                 height= 500,
                 width= 700)
```

Could someone would be able to help me get what Is wrong ? ( I know ,almost everything :-) )
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the second half of the code you have:

```
sht1 = wb.sheets[0]
wb.sheets.add('Aspire Employees Graph')
sht1.range('R1').value = df2
```

What `wb.sheets[0]` is returning is the very first sheet of the workbook.  Towards the beginning you have the first section, which is:

```
sht = wb.sheets[0]
sht.name = "Aspire Manager Graph"
sht.range('R1').value = df3
```

As you use `wb.sheets[0]` both times, but haven't inserted a sheet at the beginning, you are just referring to the same sheet.  The addition of the new sheet is correct, but you haven't set that as variable `sht1`.

Instead, for the second section, you could re-write to the following, combining the two lines into one so that the variable is the correct sheet:

```
sht1 = wb.sheets.add('Aspire Employees Graph')
sht1.range('R1').value = df2
```

## Edit

To change the colour of the sheet tab:

```
sht1.api.Tab.ColorIndex = 3
```

The full list of colours can be found in the VBA [ColorIndex documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.colorindex).

For more specific colours, see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72896912/how-to-get-set-the-colour-of-the-worksheet-tab-using-xlwings-in-python).

Comment: Thank you so much Rawson!Would it be possible color the sheets label ?

Comment: Yes, this is possible, see the edit above.